# Is there a thing such as custom boolean attributes in HTML?

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

In HTML5 we can use custom [data-* attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/). However, as I understand it and considering they are *attributes* I expect them to require a string value. Is there an alternative in HTML that allows for custom *properties*, i.e. boolean value properties such as `checked`, `required`, `hidden` and so on.

Let's say I have a website for a school. Let's also say that I want some elements on the page to be interactive with the user if the user is a teacher, but not when they are students. In JavaScript it would be nice to attach events to some element that has the property `teacher-can-interact` or similar. I obviously know I can use classes or data-attributes, but classes don't seem semantically pretty, and data-attributes with a `yes` value are ridiculous in my opinion - that's what properties are for.

So, is there any way, or are there any plans, to support custom properties? (Not attributes.)

Edit: by property I refer to the distinction made in jQuery since version 1.6(.1) where properties are mainly the *boolean attributes*. I would expect (want) the code below to return true, but it returns an empty string.

```js
console.log($("div").prop("data-intrusive"));
console.log($("div").attr("data-intrusive"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-intrusive></div>
```

Obviously, there are work-arounds like checking the `typeof` and things like that. But it would be nice if there was a way to create custom boolean attributes that return true or false in JavaScript rather than a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DOM properties like checked, selected, disabled or hidden , you will get boolean value

```
$("div").attr("data-intrusive");
```

**.attr()** will get the value of attribute and not the boolean value.
.attr() will try to get value of data-intrusive and if you observe the value of the data-intrusive in the DOM it is empty string

```
<div data-intrusive="">1</div>
```

**.prop()** will return Boolean value for boolean attributes and property value for all other attributes

For example consider below example

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-intrusive style="color:red" hidden>1</div>
```

JS:

```
console.log($("div")[0].outerHTML) //output- <div data-intrusive="" style="color:red" hidden="">1</div>

console.log($("div").prop('style'));// output-CSSStyleDeclaration {0: "color", alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: ""…}
console.log($("div").attr('style'));//output- color:red


console.log($("div").prop('hidden'));//true
console.log($("div").attr('hidden'));//hidden

console.log($("div").attr('data-intrusive'));//empty string as expected
console.log($("div").prop('data-intrusive'));//undefined as expected, as there is no property value
```

To get expected result, use hasAttribute('data-intrusive') for string values or set property for data-intrusive to boolean value to get .prop('data-intrusive') value as boolean

```
//if it is a string value
console.log($("div")[0].hasAttribute('data-intrusive'));

//if it is boolean ,then it is return the same
$("div").prop('data-intrusive','fasle');
console.log($("div").prop('data-intrusive'));
```

Codepen -
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VjgNwx

Answer (score 0):

In practice, you can use any custom attribute you want and it will work:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').getAttribute('foo'));
```

```html
<div foo="bar">My div</div>
```

Technically, it's not valid HTML markup. There are no plans to support custom attributes, that's what data-attributes were made for. You can set attributes and data-attributes to be `true` in code:

```
element.setAttribtue('teacher-can-interact', true);
element.dataset['teacher-can-interact'] = true;
```

But they will always be interpreted from the HTML as a string - that's just the way HTML works, it's not a programming language and has no concept of data types.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you are bringing data-attributes into this when I clearly say that I know them but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm talking about custom *properties*. Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ybwg4xz/). As you can see `hidden` returns true. I'd want a custom property to also return true, without the need of resorting to the semantically dubious `x=yes`.

Comment: No need to get an attitude when you're asking for help and someone is trying to offer some, and telling you that what you want was intended to be handled by something that exists. Special global attributes will have different behavior in different browsers - some might give you a boolean, some a string, and there's no predicting which will do what. The W3 doesn't define how they should be handled like they do for other properties, like `id`: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty

And as I stated in my answer, there are no plans to support custom attributes.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my comment. I was genuinely asking why you brought up data-attributes as it's confusing because I said in my OP that I know about them. Maybe I should rephrase my question: is there a way to use custom *boolean attributes* without defining a value as the string *true*. So, I would expect [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yymxhcqq/) to return true, whereas it returns an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with plain javascript using `element.hasAttribute("name");`
Check out this fidddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7fax95ve/1/

Comment: This might work in HTML, but it does not parse in SVG - the document fails to open.  You must set a value.  I use a single char like "1" or "Y" for Yes. (I'm not the downvoter...)